# How to check if a specific point is within a figure in a matrix?

Tags: algorithm, matrix, geometry

So I need a check function to see if a specific point in a matrix, say arr[3][4], is within a border, or a figure of characters. For clarification, imagine matrix char arr[10][10] below:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

As you can see, the '1' characters form a square of side length 5. I would like a bool function to return that true for arr[5][5] (0-indexed) because it is within the figure, but false for arr[1][1] because it is not. If relevant, the total size of the matrix will always be a constant 100*100, no matter the size of the '1' figure within. Also, please note that the figure will not always be a perfect polygon like the square in the example.

I could not solve this problem because in my example above, clearly both points (arr[5][5] and arr[1][1]) have the same surrounding squares, and the space is large enough so that I cannot just check if the four directions of up, right, down, and left (yes, diagonals can be ignored here) is a '1' because the '0' inside would be next to other '0's.

EDIT: I also want to clarify according to some shortcomings of answers that the thickness of sides may vary. The shape very well could be:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0
0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0
0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Therefore, counting whether the '1's on top of and to the left of the point is odd would not work.

Comment: Any other limitations on the shape? Is it always a rectangle, for example? Will the shape always be fully drawn on the matrix, i.e. part of it won't be off screen?

Comment: @JohnFilleau The shape is undefined and can be highly irregular. It is not guaranteed to be complete either. However, it is within the matrix

Comment: What does "complete" mean?

Comment: Can you edit your matrix to differentiate which 0's are "within" and which are not? For your edited matrix, it's not clear if the three 0's "kinda of inside" are within (does a diagonal close off the shape)

Comment: Once you clarify the rules of what is considered inside or not, my suggestion is to use a path finding algorithm to any edge. Or flood fill. Whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple algorithm that'll do that:

- Iterate over all elements at the edges of the matrix.
- Change all `0` elements at the edge of the matrix to `2`. (Leave any `1` elements intact.)
- Within the entire matrix, whenever a `0` borders a `2`, change that `0` to a `2` as well. Repeat this until there are no `0` elements left that are adjacent to a `2`.
- Any elements that are still `0` now are encased by `1` elements.

This is a [flood fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) starting at the edges of the matrix. It gives you all "encased" elements at once.

Answer (score 3):

So a flood fill would work, but it is quite heavy unless you want to know all the encased points.  If you just want to check one point then you could do:

- Count the number of ones in the vertical segment between points (x,0) and (x,y)
- Count the number of ones in the horizontal segment between points (0,y) and (x,y)
- If both are odd then you are inside.

Keep in mind that overlapping shapes or shapes with holes will not work with this algorithm.

So the function would look like this:

```
int inside(int x, int y)
{
    int x_count = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
        if(matrix[y][i])
            x_count++;

    int y_count = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<y;i++)
        if(matrix[i][x])
            y_count++;

    return x_count%2 && y_count%2;
};
```

A full test program looks like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int matrix1[10][10] = {
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
    {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}, 
    {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
};

int matrix2[10][10] = {
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}, 
    {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
    {0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0},
    {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0},
    {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
    {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
    {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
};

int inside(int matrix[10][10],int x, int y)
{
    int x_count = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
        if(matrix[y][i])
            x_count++;

    int y_count = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<y;i++)
        if(matrix[i][x])
            y_count++;

    return x_count%2 && y_count%2;
};

int main()
{
    printf("2,2 is %s matrix1\n",inside(matrix1,2,2)?"inside":"outside");
    printf("5,5 is %s matrix1\n",inside(matrix1,5,5)?"inside":"outside");
    printf("8,8 is %s matrix1\n",inside(matrix1,8,8)?"inside":"outside");

    printf("3,3 is %s matrix2\n",inside(matrix2,3,3)?"inside":"outside");
    printf("5,5 is %s matrix2\n",inside(matrix2,5,5)?"inside":"outside");
    printf("7,7 is %s matrix2\n",inside(matrix2,7,7)?"inside":"outside");
    
    return 0;
}
```

Try it online https://onlinegdb.com/UkkaA3vWZ

Comment: I personally find the sentence *"Check all the rows from 0 to y (at the x point) and count the number of ones."* a bit confusing, I would probably say something like *"Count the number of ones in the vertical segment between points (x,0) and (x,y)"*

Comment: Isn't this going to break down when the shape has a tiny hole, for example?

Comment: He didn't say there could be holes.  If that's important then you need a different algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

The standard algorithm only needs to scan left to right along the row you wish to check.

First, check if the element is a `1`. If it is you are “inside or on the edge”.

Otherwise, scanning from `0` to `x`:

- If you count an **odd** number of edges, you are **inside**.
- If you count an **even** number of edges, you are **outside**.

You must be careful how you count edges. An edge is one where you have a `1` both above *and* below in the surrounding 8 elements. Otherwise you have not crossed an edge (you have passed a point).

Likewise, if you hit a run of `1`s, you must still apply the above and below for both the left and right side of the run.

BTW, the only *sure* way to check is the flood-fill algorithm explained by [Jonathan S.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75367927/2706707). Everything else can be tricked.